# Problem in use of json_encode?

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I insert data with `json_encode()` in database, now i want get(`select * from <table> ...`) only `name_unitsin` of database? i want output this-> **salam** & **mokhles** & **fadat**

In database row `units`:

```
[{"name_units":"salam","price_units":"74,554","checkbox_units":["minibar","mobleman"]},
 {"name_units":"mokhles","price_units":"4,851,269","checkbox_units":["mobleman","tv"]},
 {"name_units":"fadat","price_units":"85,642","checkbox_units":["minibar","mobleman","tv"]}]
```

.

```
$query_hotel_search = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM hotel_submits WHERE name LIKE '%$hotel_search%' ORDER BY name asc");
$data = array();
foreach ($query_hotel_search->result() as $row)
{
   $units = json_decode($row->units);
   $data[] = array('name' => $row->name, 'units' =>$units['name_units']); // Line 24
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

This is output above code:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity:
>   Notice
>  Message: Undefined index: name_units
>  Line Number:
>   24
>
> [{"name":"Jack","units":null}]

Comment: it seems that $units is numeric-indexed array with 3 values for name_units: salam, mokles and fadat. But what is the correct output when the $row->name is the same for all of the units? Maybe you have to return also array of unit names? Without expected output, we can't help

Comment: output `$row->name` => `"name":"Jack"` and output `$row->units` no "$row->units['name_units']" => `[{"units":[{"name_units":"salam","price_units":"74,554","checkbox_units":["minibar","mobleman"]},{"name_units":"mokhles","price_units":"4,851,269","checkbox_units":["mobleman","tv"]},{"name_units":"fadat","price_units":"85,642","checkbox_units":["minibar","mobleman","tv"]}]}]`

Comment: what is your output when you `print_r( $units )` before line 24? you might not be getting what you expect out of the database, or from `json_decode`

Comment: @Ryan `print_r( $units )` => `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name_units] => salam [price_units] => 74,554 [checkbox_units] => Array ( [0] => minibar [1] => mobleman ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name_units] => mokhles [price_units] => 4,851,269 [checkbox_units] => Array ( [0] => mobleman [1] => tv ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name_units] => fadat [price_units] => 85,642 [checkbox_units] => Array ( [0] => minibar [1] => mobleman [2] => tv ) ) ) 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an array of `stdClass` objects as a result from `json_decode`, rather than an associative array as you'd expect. It looks like you've got an array of JSON strings located in the same cell of your DB.

Assuming that's how your DB table is structure, if you want to output

**salam** & **mokhles** & **fadat**

then try this:

```
foreach( $query_hotel_search->result() as $row ) {
    $units = json_decode( $row->units );
    $names = '';
    foreach( $units as $unit ) {
        $names .= "{$unit->name_units} & ";
    }
}
echo substr( $names, 0, -2 );
```

Comment: In output these these are just a name_units => `salam` . i want all value `name_units` of database, This means(Please note to the [In database row `units`] in first my post:): **salam** & **mokhles** & **fadat** . how is it?

Comment: is the JSON string you posted in your original question in one cell? or is there one `name_units` entry per cell? your solution really depends on how the information is stored in the database. the code i just posted will reproduce your expected output if they're all in the same cell; if they're all in different cells (which would be better), then i can modify my code to do that, too.

Comment: in your edit this line:`echo $unit->name_unit;` have this error: **Message: Trying to get property of non-object.** ?

Comment: based on your last comment, i think i'm missing some information about your database. what does the data look like while it's still in your table? that will determine how it needs to be extracted